# java java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength vs array.length

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I've got to maintain some code written by someone else who is no longer with the company.  I'm seeing several references to `java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(anArray)`. Its working, but I've never seen reflection being used to get an array length. Does anyone know the difference between:

`java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(anArray)`
and 
`anArray.length`

Is it just syntactic sugar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `anArray` is *statically typed* to an array type, you should use `anArray.length` (not a method call, btw). You'd use the reflection form if you only had a reference to the array as `Object`.

Answer (score 9):

This is a trick to get the length of an array, be it an array of primitives or an array of objects. This allows to write a method that operates on both array types.

Consider a method that prints the content of any type of array:

```
void print(Object array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(array); i++) {
        System.out.println(Array.get(array, i));
    }
}
```

This will work with int[] or Object[] parameters.

Otherwise you should just use the .length static field.