# WordCount Method

Tags: java, bluej, word-count

I don't understand why my code is not working. I get an error: "cannot find symbol - method getLength()," which is defined in the Array class. Any suggestions about how to make this method better? Thank you!

```
/**
     * getWordCount
     * 
     * Get a count of how many times each word occurs in an input String.
     * 
     * @param text a string containing the text you wish to analyze
     * @return a map containing entries whose keys are words, and
     *         whose values correspond to the number of times that word occurs
     *         in the input String text.
     */
    public Map<String,Integer> getWordCount(String text)
    {
         String[] parts = text.trim().split("('s|\\W)+"); 

        Map<String, Integer> wordCountMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<parts.getLength();i++)
        {
            for(String text : parts[i].toString())
            {
                if(!wordCountMap.containsKey(text))
                {
                     wordCountMap.put(text,1);
                } else {
                    int freq = wordCountMap.get(text);
                    freq++;
                    wordCountMap.put(text,freq);
                }
                return wordCountMap;
            }
            return new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: A `String[]` is not a `java.lang.reflect.Array`.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++) is right code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838090/java-java-lang-reflect-array-getlength-vs-array-getlength

Comment: Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis! That fixed it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Also, how would I go about iterating through an Array for a specific word (String) and then returning how often that String occurred?

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one issue with your code.

The following changes might help

```
public Map<String,Integer> getWordCount(String text)
{
    String[] parts = text.trim().split("('s|\\W)+"); 

    Map<String, Integer> wordCountMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String part : parts)
    {
        if(!wordCountMap.containsKey(part))
        {
             wordCountMap.put(part,1);
        } else {
            int freq = wordCountMap.get(part);
            freq++;
            wordCountMap.put(part,freq);
        }
    }
    return wordCountMap;
}
```

The following test code gives a size of 5 which seems to confirm what you looking to do in your code.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = getWordCount(" the fox jumped over the moon ");
System.out.println("size:" + map.size());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot. I could not figure out how to iterate through the Array and get it to work with the String.